# Call a static method of a custom class

Tags: powershell, static-methods

I am writing a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) script which use my own DLL in it:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("E:\Group.School.dll")
```

I want to access a **static** method in `Student class`. That static method has been overloaded.

```
Class Student
{        
    public static sting GetData(string id)
    {
        ....
    }

    public static sting GetData(string fName, string lName)
    {
        ....
    }        
}
```

From PowerShell I am going to access the **first method** like below:

```
$data = [Group.School.Student]::GetData
$data.Invoke("myId")
```

This gives me an exception saying

> Exception calling "Invoke" with "1" argument(s): "Exception calling "GetData" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.""

Answer (score 8):

The original code contains a few typos (e.g. `Class`, `sting`) and a mistake - the class has to be `public`.

Here is the corrected code which works without errors:

```
# the corrected code added inline (might be in a DLL, as well):
Add-Type @'
public class Student
{
    public static string GetData(string id)
    {
        return "data1";
    }

    public static string GetData(string fName, string lName)
    {
        return "data2";
    }
}
'@

# call the static method:
[Student]::GetData('myId')
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
[Group.School.Student]::GetData('myId')
```

Comment: Same error **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your dll containing the Student class is not compiled with "Any CPU" option in Visual Studio, try compiling it for x86.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.  The answer with the most upvotes clearly conflicts with your statement.